# Create bivariate histogram from binned pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns **a** and **b**.

```
a    b

23   1.1
76   2.1
98   3.4
18   1.4
```

I have binned b in 10 bins and want to create a histogram consisting of number of **a** values in bins of **b**.

```
dg = pd.cut(x=df['b'] , bins=10)
```

I want a histogram with x axis as the bins (of **b**) and y-axis as the total **a** values (like 23+18+...) in those bins.
How should I approach this problem?